# Is memory defragmentation still relevant on 64 bit systems

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, x86-64

On a 32 bit systems, the virtual address space was limited to 4GB, so it was important to defragment the memory, so that that we do not run out of address space just due to fragmentation problem.

However, In 64 bit systems, we have an address space of virtually unlimited size. To prevent overuse of the RAM or swap space, the *free* function could just return the memory to the OS when an unused block is of size bigger than 4096 (Page size) and never use that address again. So while I know freeing RAM is important, I'm saying that defragmentation is not.

So, my question is if memory defragmentation is still relevant. If not, then perhaps we can have a different sort of *malloc/free* for 64 bit systems, which might be more efficient if it does not try to spend time defragmenting memory. At least for applications that we know are not gonna use the whole 256 TB of address space. What are your opinions?

Comment: `In 64 bit systems, we have an address space of virtually unlimited size` How's that, then?

Comment: Existing `malloc`/`free` implementations typically don't make any effort to defragment memory because they can't. They can't move things around in virtual memory and they have no idea how long an allocation will be around for, so they can't try to pick the chunks to give out wisely.

Comment: @MetallicPriest : Sorry to have to say this but this is a Q&A site, not an opinion site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Typical modern 64-bit operating systems support a 256TB address space. That's likely to remain effectively virtually unlimited (compared to physical memory, which is the relevant comparison here) for a long time. You'd need some amazing fragmentation!

Comment: And MetallicPriest should know that

Comment: "256TB should be enough for anyone" ;-)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: In some systems 256TB is already not an unimaginable quantity of memory.

Comment: As physical memory supported goes up, so will virtual memory. But that is a very good point. (Though I think his question was implicitly about 64-bit systems *today*, not the future. -- Whether now is the time to rethink the design.)

Comment: In practice, I imagine you could fairly easily fragment 256TB on a big enough system if you do a lot of memory-mapping of gigantic files. That immediately turns "the order of magnitude of RAM" into "the order of magnitude of storage arrays". I can imagine a 256TB storage array.

Comment: @SteveJessop Right, but that's not what his question is about. It's not about fragmenting file mappings but fragmenting ordinary memory allocations.

Comment: David Schwartz: I know malloc/free don't move data around, but at least they try to reuse the freed memory for future allocations to reduce fragmentation. No?

Comment: @MetallicPriest True, but they don't do it so much to reduce fragmentation as to reduce total memory usage (when sub-page allocations are concerned) and to improve caching. If you didn't re use address space at all, you actually could run out of virtual address space in an application that "churned" memory a lot.

Comment: "when an unused block is of size bigger than 4096 (Page size) and never use that address again" and what does your implementation do when each of these 4k blocks is occupied by a single byte allocation only? then you have netto fragmentation rate of 1:4096... and available address space is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @David: fair enough, I am of course wrong to relate fragmentation and block-coalescing in `malloc` to the same thing in the OS's lower-level allocators. They're completely separate. In that case, in my effort to get to 256TB of address space actually in use, I wonder how big of a swap partition Linux supports. Maybe not 256TB ;-)

Comment: @Steve: Just turn on overcommit and Linux will happily give you 256TB without swap to back it... :-)

Answer (score 4):

It'll always be relevant, but not because of the lack of address space, but because of memory coherency. Thanks to the 32bit systems we also already have many algorithms for low fragmentation allocators and free-space coalescing allocators, and there is no reason why they would just be ignored on 64bit systems, they don't add much overhead at all and the amortized overhead may even *drop* on a 64 bit system).

> However, In 64 bit systems, we have an address space of virtually unlimited size.

Not even close, most systems only have 16TB of addressable virtual space, as currently only 44 bits are used for addressing [as per AMD64's specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details) (kernel address space uses the upper bit as well).

Comment: Also, the suggestion in the question of "and never use that address again" would go down the drain pretty fast. It's quite easy for an application to allocate 256TB over its entire lifespan. (and it would put more strain on the OS, current allocators only return memory to the OS in quite specific circumstances, to have every free() of > a pagesize result in a syscall that fiddles with memory mappings would not help in making things faster)

Comment: @nos: yeah, most of Googles BigTable based services probably break that regularly (hourly)

Comment: Also, there's cost associated with virtual address space usage due to page tables and the like. It's small, but if you're wasting TBs, it will add up.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: wasteful design/implementation is bad no matter how many resources you have IMO.

Comment: @Necrolis: although you are right in every specific use case, I find it sometimes difficult to define the right trade-off between wasteful and keeping the code maintainable.